# Branches of $\sqrt{z}$ when removing the negative real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

In Complex Analysis by Ahlfors, he defines the complex square root $w(z)=\sqrt{z}$ on the complement of the negative axis $\Re(z)\leqslant 0$ to be the square root with positive real part. He then shows that this is continuous as follows:
$$|z-a|=|w^2(z)-w^2(a)|=|w(z)-w(a)||w(z)+w(a)| \geqslant |w(z)-w(a)|\cdot\Re(w(a))$$ which implies that given $\epsilon>0$ we can see that letting $\delta=\epsilon \cdot \Re(w(a))$ we have
$$|z-a|<\delta \implies |w(z)-w(a)|\leqslant\frac{|z-a|}{\Re(w(a))}<\epsilon.$$
I can see that he used the fact that we cut out the negative real axis when dividing by $\Re(w(a))$ as the square roots of negative reals are purely complex. But, why did he decide the square root to be the one with positive real value? I believe that the same computation shows that if we define
\begin{cases}
        0\leqslant \text{Arg}(w)\leqslant \pi/2 & \text{if } 0\leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi/2\\
        \pi\leqslant \text{Arg}(w)\leqslant 3\pi/2 & \text{if } \pi/2\leqslant \theta<\pi\\
\pi/2\leqslant \text{Arg}(w)\leqslant\pi & \text{if } \pi<\theta\leqslant 3\pi/2\\
3\pi/2\leqslant \text{Arg}(w)\leqslant 2\pi & \text{if } 3\pi/2\leqslant\theta\leqslant2\pi
    \end{cases}
then we can replace $\Re(w(a))$ with $|\Re(w(a))|$ and then $w$ is continuous. But we would have 16 choices for a continuous square root on $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}^{\leqslant0}$ which seems untrue. Is there an error in my understanding here?

Comment: First, you can choose a branch cut wherever you want. Any line (or even any simple curve) from the branch point at $0$ to the branch point at $\infty$. Second, your proposal has two different arguments for $w$ at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$ which is definitely... Not well defined, unless you mean you want to add more than one branch cut (which is fine; you just have to make sure things glue together nicely afterward into the correct Riemann Surface)

Comment: I'm only wondering about cutting the negative real axis. Sure I agree, the first case can be modified to make the upper bound  for $\theta$ strict and the fourth can be modified to make the lower bound strict. I'm wondering if it really is possible to get $16$ distinct continuous square roots from a single branch.

Comment: Only two branches exist (the proof is easy since the branch is uniquely defined by the value at a point and there are just two possible values; here since cutting the negative reals means polar representation $re^{it}, -\pi<t<\pi$, the branches are $\sqrt r e^{it/2}$ and its negative - the first one which is positive on the reals (and more generally has positive real part for all numbers in the domain) is the principal one by convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ denote the complex plane with the non-positive real axis removed. There are *precisely two* branches of square root on $D$, each the negative of the other. (A *branch of square root* in $D$ is a holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ satisfying $f(z)^{2} = z$ for all $z$ in $D$.) The diagram shows the real parts of the two branches, whose graphs are mirror images across the $z$-plane:

[image: Real parts of the branches of the square root]

One branch, the so-called *principal branch* (gray), is positive on the positive reals, and extends the real square root (yellow) to $D$. The other branch (green mesh) is negative on the positive reals. That's about as close as one can get to answering "Why did [Ahlfors] decide the square root to be the one with positive real value?"

As for what appears to be wrong with the "sixteen branches" argument, in the "piecewise" formulas of the original question there are discontinuities in $\operatorname{Arg}(w)$ on the ray where $\theta = \pi/2$ (the stated value jumps from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$), and similarly discontinuities where $\theta = 3\pi/2$ and where $\theta = 0$ (a.k.a., $2\pi$). If we could independently select branches on each quarter plane, there *would* be $2^{4} = 16$ branches of square root. Continuity, however, reduces our freedom to just two choices.