Branch points of $\sqrt{z-1}$
Let, $f(z)=\sqrt{z-1}$
I am reading the book "Visual complex analysis" by Tristan Needham and after reading the section of branch points and branch cuts, I gave myself this definition of a branch point but it seems that I am misunderstanding the concept.
"A branch point to a function is a point around which the function fails to return to it's original value after traveling a closed loop across it".
Now according to my understanding traveling a loop around the origin for the function $f(z)$ should give the same value as we started (as $z=0$ is not a branch point)
I start my loop at $z=i$ then,
$$f(z)=(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})^{\frac{1}{2}}=2^{1/4}e^{i\pi/8}$$
.Now I traverse a circular loop around the origin and reach again the point $z=i$. This increases the angle by $2\pi$ radians. So now,
$$f(z)=(\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi/4+2\pi)})^{1/2}=-2^{1/4}e^{i\pi/8}$$
My question:-
If $z=0$ isn't a branch point then why is the value is not same after completing the loop?
Edit:-
I found my mistake. It's not the argument of $1-z$ that increases by $2\pi$ it's $z$.

As long as your loop around the origin is small enough not to encircle the branch point $z=1$, the argument of $z-1$ will return to its starting value (not increase by $2\pi$).

@Hans Lundmark, I don't see how? I request you to be bit more specific. Assume that my loop doesn't includes the point $z=1$ . Why won't the argument increase by$2\pi$ after one complete irregular rotation.

The $z - 1$ instead of $z$ in the radicand may be creating a needless conceptual complication? Whether or no, the picture here may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767446/branches-of-sqrtz-when-removing-the-negative-real-axis

Consider first the circle $\gamma_1(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$ around $z=0$, $\theta = \Theta+2\pi n, \; n\in \mathbb{Z}, \;-\pi<\Theta\leq \pi$
We want to evaluate $f(e^{i\theta}) = \sqrt{e^{i\theta} -1}$.
First, note that:
$$ |e^{i\theta}-1| = \sqrt{\left(\cos \theta-1\right)^2+\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}$$
$$ \arg(e^{i\theta}-1)= \operatorname{atan2}\left(\cos\theta-1,\sin \theta\right)$$
where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the formal computation of the argument
Therefore
$$e^{i\theta}-1 = \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta}e^{i\operatorname{atan2}\left(\cos\theta-1,\sin \theta\right)}$$
$$ \Longrightarrow e^{i\left(\Theta +2\pi n\right)}-1 = \sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\Theta +2\pi n\right)}e^{i\operatorname{atan2}\left(\cos\left(\Theta +2\pi n\right)-1,\sin \left(\Theta +2\pi n\right)\right)}$$
Since $\sin,\cos$ are $2\pi$-periodic:
$$ \Longrightarrow e^{i\left(\Theta+2\pi n\right)}-1 = \sqrt{2-2\cos\Theta }e^{i\operatorname{atan2}\left(\cos\Theta-1,\sin \Theta \right)}$$
By the de Moivre's theorem:
$$ \Longrightarrow \sqrt{e^{i\left(\Theta+2\pi n\right)}-1} = \sqrt[4]{2-2\cos\Theta }e^{\frac{i}{2}\left[\operatorname{atan2}\left(\cos\Theta-1,\sin \Theta \right)+2\pi k\right]} \quad k=0,1$$
If $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, n=0, k=0 $
$$ \sqrt{e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}-1} = \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{atan2}\left(-1,1\right)} = \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\left(\arctan(-1)+\pi\right)} =  \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{3\pi i}{8}}  $$
If $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, n=1, k=0$
$$  \sqrt{e^{\frac{5\pi i}{2}}-1} =  \sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{3\pi i}{8}}$$
Both are equal after one loop.
So, zero is not a branch point of $\sqrt{z-1}$.
Now, consider the circle around $1$, $\gamma_{2}(\theta) = 1+e^{i\theta}, \; \theta = \Theta+2\pi n,\; n\in \mathbb{Z}, \; -\pi<\Theta\leq \pi$
We want to evaluate
$$f(1+e^{i\theta}) = \sqrt{(1+e^{i\theta})-1} =  \sqrt{e^{i\left(\Theta+2\pi n \right)}} = e^{\frac{i\Theta}{2}+\pi n + \pi k} \quad k=0,1$$
If $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, n=0, k=0$
$$ f(1+e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}})= e^{\frac{{i\pi}}{4}}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
If $\Theta = \frac{\pi}{2}, n=1, k=0$
$$ f(1+e^{\frac{5\pi i}{2}})= e^{\frac{{5\pi i}}{4}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} $$
So, after one loop we fail get the same value due to the fact that $z=1$ is a branch point.
